# Rundeck EC2 Plugin Regions

Tags: rundeck

Has anyone been able to pull nodes from EC2 in multiple regions to populate a node list? Can't seem to see EC2 host in other regions other than AWS East. I have the plugin for AWS EC2 in Rundeck. It does pull instances in AWS East.

I do have the ec2-node-plugin installed and it is working for the east region, but not others.

How do you get the plugin to look at a different or all regions?

Answer (score 0):

You can add various EC2 node-sources in your project (for each region for example). Make sure that the region is defined as [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#ec2_region).

To configure it you must follow [these](https://github.com/rundeck-plugins/rundeck-ec2-nodes-plugin#usage) instructions.